# Unicode characters in IDLE

Tags: python, unicode, python-idle

I am just learning python. I read about Unicode characters and strings and was trying to print out a recently introduced symbol as mentioned here - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm

However my attempt in the IDLE prompt:

```
u"\u20b9"
```

just echoes the same expression instead of producing the character. I am not sure if this is a problem with fonts or Unicode versions or if I am doing something wrong. Please help!

Comment: What did you try? `print u"\u20b9"` works for me

Comment: What are »special« Unicode characters? To me they are all quite normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work perfectly fine: `print u"\u20b9"`

I'm guessing you were only typing `u"\u20b9"` without the print function.

Comment: I was doing that! Now I get that box-like character. So I guess the font isn't supported. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> s=u"\u20b9"
>>> print s
₹
```

Or this:

```
>>> print u'rupee: {}'.format(u"\u20b9")
rupee: ₹
```

Comment: It's not working for me. Any idea why? I'm using Python 2.7.1 - could the version have anything to do with it?

Comment: No thats very basic and it should work perfectly fine with you. You must have done something wrong.

Comment: @user1562715 My guess is that IDLE is not compiled correctly or you do not have the ability to print that code point on your computer. It works in IDLE for me too. Try the Python command interpreter.